# Is there a way to tell iOS which version to put on simulator?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

So I just want to test my application on an earlier version of iOS. It seems that there's no way to change the iOS version on the simulator, is there a different way to tell the simulator which iOS to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XCode --> Preferences --> Components
```

This will allow you to install older versions of the simulators.  Then when you deploy from Xamarin you can pick which simulator image to use.

Comment: YES! thanks! This seems to work. I didn't test yet, but I'm downloading the iOS 8 sim as we speak.